# Schroedinger equation for wave functional (QFT)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, classical-field-theory

As far as I'm aware you can solve for the wave functional $\Psi[\phi]$ of a field using the Schrodinger equation $$i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=H\Psi.$$

1. Should $H$ here be the Hamiltonian, or the Hamiltonian density?
2. If it's the Hamiltonian, is there a version of this equation for the Hamiltonian density?
3. Would assuming a certain form for the functional like $\Psi\sim e^{-\omega \phi^2}$ be of any use in simplifying the equation?

I'm pretty new to QFT so excuse me if the question is poorly formulated.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395051/energies-of-this-field-hamiltonian/395083#395083).  1. Hamiltonian 2.yes, but *why*??? it would be quite misguided. 3. for quadratic hamiltonians, only, yes, but, again, work with functionals, not functions. Have you understood your Jackiw or Hatfield textbook review?

Comment: 2- I know the Hamiltonian density for this field, so I wanted to use canonical quantization to get an equation for $\Psi$ that contains $\phi$ and $d\Psi / d\phi$. If i use the total Hamiltonian I have to deal with the integral in 3d space. Then again I'm new to QFT so probably should check those text books. Thanks.

Comment: "2- I know the Hamiltonian density for this field..." So... integrate over all space to get the Hamiltonian... what is the problem?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525851/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142180/226902

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall, from Hatfield's textbook (QFT of point particles and strings) & Jackiw's [review](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/22/056/22056871.pdf#page=88) that the functional equation you are emulating is just that, a *functional* equation the extension of an infinite sum of canonical pairs $[q_i,p_j]=i\hbar \delta_{ij}$ to
$$ [\phi(x),\pi(y)]\propto \delta(x-y). $$
So, just as the Hamiltonian in QM deals with all degrees of freedom, just so in QFT,
$$
H\psi[\phi]=  \int\!\! d^3 x  \left (-\frac{\delta^2}{\delta\phi(x)^2}  +\phi(x)O\phi(x)+... \right )\psi[\phi],
$$
where the ellipses (...) suggests cubic and higher terms in the potential, rarely used. $O$ is a normally nonlocal operator, i.e., $$
  O \phi(x) = \int \! d^3y ~O(x-y) \phi(y),
$$
[such as](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/395083/66086) $O=m^2-\nabla^2$, etc. I've left the time dependence implicit throughout.

It is then evident that the ground state of the quadratic Hamiltonian is
$$
\propto e^{-\tfrac{1}{2} \int d^3z ~\phi(z) \sqrt{O} \phi(z) }, 
$$
but you must attend to the δ-functions.

- When confused, try to consider uncoupled oscillators, i.e. $O$ a constant.
- PS if you insist on using functions instead of functionals, you can always convert the latter to the former by sticking in gonzo gratuitous delta functions,
  $$
  H'[\phi]=\int d^3 x ~~{\cal H}(x)  \delta (x-y)=  {\cal H}(y),
  $$
  but *why*??

---

<sub>A more explicit definition for $\sqrt O$ is clearest in 1d space. For
$$
\sqrt{O}\phi(x)\equiv \int\! dy~ K(x-y)\phi(y). ~~~\leadsto \\
O\phi[x]= \sqrt{O}\sqrt{O}\phi(x) =\int\! dydz~ K(x-y) K(y-z)\phi(z) ~~~\implies \\
O(x-z)= \int\! dy ~~K(x-y) K(y-z),
$$
the equation defining the kernel of the square root.</sub>

Comment: To clarify one point that confused me at first passing, the reason $(m^2-\nabla^2)$ is non-local is that its integration kernel is $(m^2-\nabla^2)\delta(x-y)$; namely, $\nabla^2$ has to hit both the delta function and $\phi(x)$, in $O\phi(x)$.

Comment: Yes; gradients are nonlocal. You may simulate them with a discrete number of point canonical variables, poorly.