# Are there alternative but equivalent formalisms for Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-interpretations

I am curious if there are any alternative formulations of QFT generally, in the same way that QM can be reformulated into different, but equivalent formulations beyond Schrodinger wave mechanics and projectors on abstract Hilbert spaces?

Even if "traditional" QFT is the most useful form to use, I still think it would be interesting from a conceptual, philosophical, and pedagogical perspective to look beyond the standard presentation if they exist.

Comment: relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214552/84967

Answer (score 3):

Because QFT is the quantum mechanics of fields, any equivalent formulations of QM also give rise to equivalent formulations of QFT. For instance, the path integral formulation of QM also applies to QFT.